# With Navigation Timing API, in what situations does the loadEventStart get returned as 0?

Tags: javascript, performance, w3c, navigation-timing-api

I'm trying to gather some data around page load times. I'm calculating it by

```
pageLoadTime = loadEventStart - navigationStart
```

However, this is occasionally returning a (huge) negative number. It looks like the loadEventStart is returning 0. The only way we can reproduce this locally is when we get a timeout, but this code shouldn't be run in that situation.

Comment: don't you have the numbers in front of you?

Comment: Rephrased the question to make more sense.

Comment: using navigationStart includes DNS lookup, maybe you want to use `performance.timing.loadEventStart - performance.timing.fetchStart` to measure only your server's performance.

Comment: I'm looking to find out why I'm getting negative numbers though, any suggestions for investigating the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting negative numbers because performance.timing.loadEventStart will be 0 until the load event is fired per the spec at http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#dom-performancetiming-loadstart meanwhile the performance.navigation.start is an actual date in milliseconds.

Comment: So, the problem with that is the code to calculate this only gets run after the load event is fired.

Comment: I ran into this yesterday. Try putting your code in a setTimeout of 500 milliseconds.